# CSS For Footer Color and Menu Drop Down Color

Tags: css, menu, footer, background-color

Im trying to change to the color in both the drop down menu, as well as the footer background color of the site  http://ablecareinhome.com/

Ive tried numerous css tweeks to make this change, but I am at a stale mate.  I was able to get the nenu buttons themselves to change using the following:

```
#menu li.current-menu-item a, 
#menu li.current-menu-parent a, 
#menu li.current_page_parent a, 
#menu li a.selected, 
#menu li a:hover, 
#menu li.current_page_item a {
    background: url("../images/menu-bg.png") repeat-x scroll center top #00a99d !important;
}
```

this is the color i am going for in the other footer and menu parts. #00a99d

Any help is appreciated.  As a side note, this theme allows internal css options/modifications without building a full childs theme.  It is done from the dashboard, and stylesheets are coming from external source it appears.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

well see the css here

```
 #menu .sf-menu li li {
font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
text-transform:capitalize;
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-color: #00a99d;}
```

As for footer its an image  [see the link](http://ablecareinhome.com/wp-content/themes/colorway/images/footer-bg.png)

you can remove the backgroun image and
edit this css

```
 .footer-container {
background:url(../images/footer-bg.png); remove this
background-color: # #00a99d;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I tried the same thing via the internal css modifier and several other versions, but none of them seem to work.  Any other thoughts?  

Im afraid the footer command didnt work either.  Thanks in advance

I was bale to change the visual (no hover or drop down menu color with the follow)

'#menu li.current-menu-item a, #menu li.current-menu-parent a, #menu li.current_page_parent a, #menu li a.selected, #menu li a:hover, #menu li.current_page_item a {
    background: url("../images/menu-bg.png") repeat-x scroll center top #00a99d !important;;
    color: #FFFFFF;

Comment: not sure if the last message had your name tagged. Thx!

Comment: the !important   did it.   Thanks for your help.